# Setting global attributes in Flask framework

Tags: python, flask

I am working on a small web project using Flask/Python. This is a simple client side application without database.

I want to set the REST service address as a global attribute, but haven't figured out how to do that.

I know that attributes can be seted in flask.config like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['attribute_name'] = the_service_address
```

but the Blueprint module cannot access the 'app' object.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Within a request context (i.e. in a view/handler) you can access the config on the `current_app`

```
from flask import current_app
current_app.config['attribute_name']
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work globally per the question - an attempt to access the `current_app` outside of the request context will result in `RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like adding an attribute to any python object:

```
def create_web_app():
    app = Flask('foods')
    setattr(app, 'cheese', CheeseService())
```